# How do I make fields on a publishing page display as hyperlinks?

Tags: publishing-page

I have a publishing page in which I have some fields which are regular text fields. What I want is for those fields be displayed as hyperlinks, and for one email field be displayed a mailto link.

One thing I observed is that If I place a OOTB contact field which is of type user, all the links in the are formatted as hyperlinks. But I don't want the contact field on the page.

Can someone please tell me how I can make my fields hyperlinks on a publishing page?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the hyperlink field on the publishing page.:)

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: I don't exactly want a hyperlink field.what I need is a regular text box and when user enter value in it in edit mode it transforms to a hyperlink when the page is in display mode..Like I said if I place a contact field of type user on the page it automatically formats the text as hyperlink..I checked the source code of the page and there doesn't appear to be any extra javascript or anything like that so I was wondering how does putting a contact field on the page turns just regular text into hyperlinks..